# Unable to connect with socket.io using node.js and nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io

I've set up a socket.io with node.js running behind nginx. The main domain is running on nginx and sub-domain is being proxied to node.js. All the REST APIs are working fine, but when it comes to socket connections, I do see the handshake in the logs, but client is not able to get response apparently. Below is the log from node.js, and further below are the configs I'm using. Any ideas why it's not working?

```
info  - handshake authorized 7WtMDKRY1tPb97CORlJ4
debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/7WtMDKRY1tPb97CORlJ4
debug - set heartbeat interval for client 7WtMDKRY1tPb97CORlJ4
debug - client authorized for 
debug - websocket writing 1::
debug - clearing poll timeout
debug - jsonppolling writing io.j[0]("8::");
debug - set close timeout for client JoDWOVTvLg7SdYpNRlJ2
debug - jsonppolling closed due to exceeded duration
debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/xhr-polling/7WtMDKRY1tPb97CORlJ4?t=1368925686996
debug - setting poll timeout
debug - discarding transport
debug - cleared heartbeat interval for client 7WtMDKRY1tPb97CORlJ4
debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/jsonp-polling/7WtMDKRY1tPb97CORlJ4?t=1368925696997&i=0
debug - setting poll timeout
debug - discarding transport
debug - clearing poll timeout
debug - clearing poll timeout
debug - jsonppolling writing io.j[0]("8::");
debug - set close timeout for client 7WtMDKRY1tPb97CORlJ4
debug - jsonppolling closed due to exceeded duration
debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/jsonp-polling/7WtMDKRY1tPb97CORlJ4?t=1368925717060&i=0
debug - setting poll timeout
debug - discarding transport
debug - cleared close timeout for client 7WtMDKRY1tPb97CORlJ4
debug - clearing poll timeout
debug - jsonppolling writing io.j[0]("8::");
debug - set close timeout for client 7WtMDKRY1tPb97CORlJ4
debug - jsonppolling closed due to exceeded duration
debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/jsonp-polling/7WtMDKRY1tPb97CORlJ4?t=1368925737199&i=0
debug - setting poll timeout
debug - discarding transport
debug - cleared close timeout for client 7WtMDKRY1tPb97CORlJ4
debug - fired close timeout for client JoDWOVTvLg7SdYpNRlJ2
info  - transport end (close timeout)
```

Nginx config:

```
upstream app_yourdomain {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

# the nginx server instance
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com;

    # pass the request to the node.js server with the correct headers and much more can be added, see nginx config options
    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

      tcp_nodelay on;
      proxy_pass http://app_yourdomain/;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }
 }
```

Socket.io is running in 127.0.0.1:3000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running a new enough version of nginx? WebSocket support was introduced in nginx version 1.3.13. `nginx -v` to see what version you have. See also https://chrislea.com/2013/02/23/proxying-websockets-with-nginx/

Comment: I've installed it through `apt-get` recently and upgraded the whole system recently, but only have 1.1.19 running. I will try to upgrade it right now.

Comment: I am connecting socket from client side,so how to access it in code, i mean how to access proxy url inside var socket = io.connect('/explorer/socket',{
      'reconnect': true,
      'reconnection delay': 500
    });